# Alamofire put request remove backslashes in request json string

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

I'm working in a cocoa app and trying to do a PUT request using Alamofire 4.
Here is my current function. 
ResponseMessage is a Codable struct.

```
 func putData(responseMessage:ResponseMessage) {

    let url = "\(responseMessage.uri)?overwrite=true"

    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string:url)!)
    request.httpMethod = HTTPMethod.put.rawValue

    do {

        let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(responseMessage)
        request.httpBody = data
        request = try JSONEncoding.default.encode(request)
        Alamofire.request(request).validate().responseJSON { response in

            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                print("success in Put ") 
            case .failure(let error):
                print("error in Put Section ==>", error)
            }
        }

    } catch(let e) {
        print("Error " , e)
    }
}
```

the put request is working fine but it adds back slashes in the json request string

```
{\"messageId\":\"1d657365-a460-4ee1-911d-1599bf398409\",\"status\":3,\"result\":{\"type\":0,\"content\":\"blahblahblah\",\"code\":0},\"transactionid\":0,\"uri\":\"http:\/\/someUrl\",\"id\":\"131DF57B-FB54-4DEA-957B-2DF72D37B8FA\"}
```

Server does not accept this with the backslashes. I tried to pass as parmeter not as http body, but still I'm having the same issue.

Is there any way that I can send something like this to the server

```
{"messageId":"1d657365-a460-4ee1-911d-1599bf398409","status":3,"result":{"type":0,"content":"blahblahblah","code":0},"transactionid":0,"uri":"http:\/\/someUrl","id":"131DF57B-FB54-4DEA-957B-2DF72D37B8FA"}
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's doing this because you said it to do it, more precisely in this line

```
request = try JSONEncoding.default.encode(request)
```

you already had an json encoded data, when you do it again, you are treating this data as a simple string, and than json escapes the special characters.

If you remove that line it should work

You might have to set the content-type of the request also

```
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```

but it's not always required

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I removed it and tried it. Still I was getting the same result. I think by default Alamofire is adding those slashed. I found that "allowLossyConversion " can be used somewhere here. But not quite sure how to use it

Comment: I'm not getting that error here, I copied your code but it is working fine. Those backslashes appear in the print statement though but not in the request. Are you sure that the problem is not in the serverside?

Comment: Try changing the url to `https://httpbin.org/put`. This is a service to test url requests, and you will see that the request is properly formatted.

Comment: I have tried with that url ,  from the success response I getting back from that url I can see it has args, data, files, forms, headers and json. In the json it has the right content but in the data it has content with back slashes :(

Comment: I have tried the same json from a seperate rest client ( not Alamofire ) and it worked when I send the original json sting as body

Comment: That backslashes in the data are just in this representation that I was talking about, they are not really there. The JSON field you got in the response is that data parsed, so your request has the json encoded correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it was actually a server side probably after all.